# Chuwi Lapbook Pro touchpad issue

Tags: drivers, touchpad

I have a Chuwi Lapbook Pro with Ubuntu installed and everything works well except for the touchpad which sometimes works, sometimes doesn't.In the second case there is no way to get it works so i have to restart pc (with no guarantee that will work on the next bootup). I have already tried [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/512280/chuwi-lapbook-air-14-touchpad-recognized-but-not-fully-working) solution but it didn't work. After some research i saw that you need to recompile the kernel by adding the touchpad driver or something similar, but i have no idea where to start. Would you help me please?
Thank you in advance

Edit: i'm using Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Comment: Are you using Ubuntu? Which release?

Comment: @Pilot6 20.04 LTS

Comment: Thank you @Melebius! In the link that i provided, the second answer is giving a a link to a guide but is not available anymore